Capture output of interactive prompt
I am trying to write a script capture the output of an interactive prompt:
gh gist view > $tempfile    
RAW=$(<$tempfile)

However, I can't seem to get the interactive prompt to show up whenever I try to capture the output of gh gist view.
If I run just gh gist view in the script, I get the interactive prompt.

Does this answer your question? How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal

The gh command (like many other commands) disables interactive behavior when output is not going to a tty device. You can use the script command to record the output to a file (script provides a virtual tty, and then records all input/output to/from that tty to a file):
script -c 'gh gist view' $tempfile

Be aware that the resulting file will be full of screen control codes (the interactive mode sets font attributes, uses cursor positioning, etc). That may not be what you want.
You haven't mentioned your goal here; possibly just running gh gist list and redirecting that output to a file would be a better choice. Alternatively, you can use gh api /gists to get a list of gists in JSON format, which is more amendable to automated parsing:
$ gh api /gists --jq '.[]|[.url,(.files|keys[0])]|@tsv'
https://api.github.com/gists/404c9304ffa0f749e08ab3a523040d3e   filters_os9.py
https://api.github.com/gists/b658c0bd766648b16c31c8ed0fc1dc1f   0001-Trace-netdev_hold-and-netdev_put.patch
https://api.github.com/gists/10bfc29f2a8bc1977a6c3eb0f2fb3de4   ax25.gdb
https://api.github.com/gists/a34061bd9ec00591004cc8a7404fce95   Makefile
https://api.github.com/gists/736a78295b49b07e9a804fe01fc4e3e3   ratecheck-github.py
.
.
.


If you want to interactively select a gist and then do something with it, gh gist view isn't your best choice. Consider using fzf to implement the interactive picker; e.g:
selected=$(
  gh api /gists --jq '.[]|[.id,(.files|keys[0])]|@tsv' |
  fzf |
  awk '{print $1}'
)
gh gist view $selected


My goal is to select a gist and capture the raw text output of the gist (the same output ascalling gh gist view <id> -r directly). Then i simply just tail -n +3 <<< $RAW to remove some header lines I don't want and I have the raw text script from a Gist I can do whatever with (like pass to Docker as a Dockerfile, for example).

I've updated the answer with a suggestion that might help out.
